# how do I set the location of pegman?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I have been trying to find a way to set the location on peg man in google maps via programming instead of dragging and dropping.Is there a way to set the location of pegman on google maps programmatically?

Comment: Any solutions about this question?

Answer (score 1):

better late than never, but you're looking for the pano function [`setPosition`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewPanorama)

setStreetView sets the pano view, but setPosition should place pegman.

Answer (score 0):

May be the below code will be helpful to you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: fenway,
    pov: {
      heading: 34,
      pitch: 10
    }
  };
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
  map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
    <div id="pano" style="position:absolute; left:410px; top: 8px; width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That almost works. But that is just setting a street view.  I need  to specifically set pegman.

Comment: Yes in the first div you can see that the pegman is positioned based on the location(position) provided....

Comment: Is there anyway to do it in js?

Comment: I have been using almost this exact code and it dose nothing with pegman. It just sets a new panorama. I could be wrong. Is there any way to show that is setting the location of the pegman?

Comment: You can just set the location (fenway variable in this case) dynamically.. so that the pegman position will be decided dynamically

Comment: Minus One. This is a lazy repost of Gmaps official example code which offers no clues about how to placing pegman via code.